# \usepackage{preview} equivalent for ConTeXt?

Tags: packages, context, context-mkiv

I would like to create a ConTeXt document cropped around a single `\starttikzpicture \stoptikzpicture`. How to achieve this by letting TeX infer the page size from the box dimensions?

Comment: Perhaps an odd question, but why use ConTeXt here? If you want to make 'stand alone' TikZ pictures the LaTeX `standalone` class is the usual go-to, and as TikZ has its own syntax there's not an obvious (to me) ConTeXt benefit. (BTW, the question in general seems like a good one: I'm wondering as an aside.)

Comment: Further to that, as `standalone` is probably a more common choice for this task, perhaps you might broaden the question to cover that option as well as directly loading `preview`?

Comment: i use [KTikZ](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) to work on figures with instant preview. those are going to be embedded in ConTeXt docs, so i’ll use `\start...` and `\stop...`, not `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}`.

Comment: You can use the `TeXpage` environment to create a standalone page for your image. All you have to do is putting `\startTEXpage` before `\starttikzpicture` and `\stopTEXpage` after `\stoptikzpicture`.

Comment: @Metafox beautiful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @Metafox's command, you can use `\startTEXpage ... \stopTEXpage` to create a page with only tikz pictures. For example,

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext

% 1st picture
\startTEXpage[offset=3mm]
\starttikzpicture
....
\stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage

% 2nd picture
\startTEXpage[offset=3mm]
\starttikzpicture
....
\stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

will create a pdf with two pages that are the size of the tikzpicture plus 3mm of offset of each side.